# Fitting and centering image inside div

Tags: html, css

I have the following structure:

```
<div style="height: 100px; width: 33%; line-height: 100px;">
   &nbsp;<img style="height: auto; width: auto; max-height: 90px; max-width: 90%; vertical-align: middle;">
</div>
```

So I want to center the image inside the parent div vertically, and keep it scaled all the time. `line-height` property takes care of centering the image.

The problem with that is that for `line-height` to work I need some text inside the div, that's why I added `&nbsp;`, but this means the image is taken down - width is set to 100% and the image is in new line - 100px below the `&nbsp;`.

If I add `display: block;` to the image, it also sets width to 100% and is taken down.

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
div > img { background-size: contain; }
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

as far as the 90% width, just wrap the image in another div with the CONTAIN option, then size that div inside your wrapper at 90%

Comment: on the link i posted it shows compatibility at IE 9.0 and greater - whats IE > 10? thats not IE anymore - that Microsoft new browser with a different name - 'EDGE' - and it is completley css3 - html5 friendly, cheers